# Android Studio 3.2.1, Oreo Target, CPU Monitor/Profiler: wrong sampling / massive slowdown

Tags: android, profiling, cpu, monitoring

I am facing a big difference between CPU Monitoring of an Android 7.1 and an Android 8.1 target by using the Android Studio 3.2 CPU Monitor/Profiler:

The target devices are identical but the Android versions differ. The sampling on the 7.1 target is quite exact and that what I also see on other versions of Android and/or target types. But when I do the same CPU profiling on the Android 8.1 target the times displayed as sampling results are of the factor of 7 bigger than under 7.1.

The strange thing is: By using the shell top command, on both targets, the application is using always 50% of CPU.

So, my conclusion is: The CPU Monitoring / Profiling on an Android 8 target with Studio 3.2 is not working correctly.

Can anybody confirm my observation?

Comment: I created a bug issue at Android / Google itself for this issue:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122829435

Comment: This issue is solved with Android Studio 3.3